# sharepoint tenant to tenant migration

Tags: sharepoint, migration, office365

I have a sharepoint site that I'd like to migrate to a new tenant. I read that I'll have to use third party tools like Metalogix to do it properly. Are there any alternative ways with which I can achieve this, preferably without a third-party tool? I just have two sites with few contents and couple of apps. I found sharepoint migration tool: http://spmtreleasescus.blob.core.windows.net/install/default.htm But I'm not sure if it's used for tenant-to-tenant migration.

Answer (score 0):

With two sites and perhaps a few document libraries, perhaps a manual migration would work: Manually create the destination sites/libraries, and for a given library, sync it. Since it's a new library, there is no content to sync, but it will create the folders, etc., on your local machine via onedrive. Open that location with windows explorer. Then, go to the source library with Internet explorer, and use the open with windows explorer command. (or, sync it also). Then, simple copy the files from the source to the target library in the windows explorer onedrive view. OneDrive will take care of syncing the files up to the library.

If have a bunch of libraries, or if you need to preserve things like file created dates, then the 3rd party tools are helpful. Another popular one is ShareGate.

Answer (score 0):

The third party tools can often also copy metadata, versions and Content Types.

Some of these tools have free, for limited amounts of data, trial versions.